# Populate array into form fields (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS so this might seem silly but I really can't figure it out

I've a list of arrays that returns from calling a `searchAll`

```
console
    0: {mobile: "12345678", lastname: "last01", firstname: "first01"}
    1: {mobile: "87654321", lastname: "last02", firstname: "first02"}
    ...
```

It needs to be populated in separate input fields using  `ng-repeat="client in ctrl.clients"`

```
<input ... ng-model="ctrl.client.firstname"
<input ... ng-model="ctrl.client.lastname"
<input ... ng-model="ctrl.client.mobile"
```

It'll show up as text if I populate the below

```
<li>First name: {{client.firstname}}</li>
<li>Last name: {{client.lastname}}</li>
<li>Mobile: {{client.mobile}}</li>
```

[Ideally, it should go into the input fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TsAd.png)

Any suggestion appreciated!

Comment: But what exactly is the problem? I see no code where you actually use `ng-repeat`. Please provide this part.

Comment: you already use `ctrl.` in ng-repeat, this will pull out a copy of the object, you don't need it to be bounded to scope, so just use `client.firstname` instead of `ctrl.client.firstname`

Comment: @Ovidiu Dolha I added parts of the codes here http://jsfiddle.net/miintea/dnvc40zc. Data comes from mongoDB. Hope this is a little clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">

  <div  ng-controller="myCtrl as ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="client in ctrl.clients">
      <input type="text" ng-model="client.firstname" />
      <input type="text" ng-model="client.lastname" />
      <input type="text" ng-model="client.mobile" />
    </div>
    <pre>{{ctrl.clients | json}}<pre>
   </div>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function() {
      this.clients = [{
        mobile: "12345678",
        lastname: "last01",
        firstname: "first01"
      }, {
        mobile: "87654321",
        lastname: "last02",
        firstname: "first02"
      }];
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I think, you just want to populate the given object.please refer above code. i have added a `<pre>` to see the live object.

Comment: I believe he has **Controller as** syntax

Comment: @Aleksey Solovey @ lihki.m.v both your suggestions are correct! THANK YOU! I just needed to remove client from ng-model!!